# Oracle query compatibility issue with versions < 12

Tags: sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I have the below-mentioned Oracle SQL query. It runs perfectly fine for versions > 12. But for versions < 12, it gives the error as `SQL command not properly ended` (ERROR CODE: ORA-00933).

Query:

```
select
    LEAST(ROUND(SUM((BLOCKS*BLOCK_SIZE)/1024/1024/1024)),200) GB, 
    to_char(COMPLETION_TIME,'MM.DD.YYYY') COMPLETION_DATE 
from 
    v$archived_log 
where 
    trunc(COMPLETION_TIME,'DD') > sysdate - 30 
group by to_char(COMPLETION_TIME,'MM.DD.YYYY') 
order by SUM((BLOCKS*BLOCK_SIZE)/1024/1024/1024) DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

What the query does: It fetches the maximum archive size from past 30 days along with the date when the max archive size occured.

I run this query using via Python using cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

is not supported on oracle 11g and prior.

You can use `rownum` approach

```
select * from
(
    select
        LEAST(ROUND(SUM((BLOCKS*BLOCK_SIZE)/1024/1024/1024)),200) GB, 
        to_char(COMPLETION_TIME,'MM.DD.YYYY') COMPLETION_DATE 
    from 
        v$archived_log 
    where 
        trunc(COMPLETION_TIME,'DD') > sysdate - 30 
    group by to_char(COMPLETION_TIME,'MM.DD.YYYY') 
    order by SUM((BLOCKS*BLOCK_SIZE)/1024/1024/1024) DESC 
) t
where rownum < 2
```

Comment: For reference, this is discussed in the cx_Oracle manual https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#limiting-rows